# microsoft bitlocker copy data in background

Tags: malware, bitlocker

I use microsoft bitlocker encryption all my disks. Some day, maybe I click on a phishing email and my computer be hacked. Hacker sends my data to his server. Is the data encrypted or plaintext in his server?

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient to give a verdict on whether the data is encrypted or not. Many factors dive in like the type of malware, data exfiltration, backdoor availability. You should better get some forensic help on your device.

Comment: The question as asked can not be answered with the information provided, it depends on the malware used.

If, however, you wonder whether the attacker obtained just the encrypted data or your plaintext data then it depends on the setup of bitlocker. Basically if you do not need to enter a password to access the files (auto-unlock) or if you unlocked manually with the malware active, then assume the attacker has the plaintext data.